# How to list all properties of a PowerShell WMI object

Tags: powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

When I look at the [Win32_ComputerSystem class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), it shows loads of properties like `Status`, `PowerManagementCapabilities`, etc. However, when in PowerShell I do the below I only get back a couple:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\drivers> Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_computersystem"

Domain              : YYY.com
Manufacturer        : VMware, Inc.
Model               : VMware Virtual Platform
Name                : LONINEGFQEF58
PrimaryOwnerName    : Authorised User
TotalPhysicalMemory : 2147016704
```

How can I see all properties?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_computersystem" | Format-List *
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_computersystem" | Format-List -Property *
```

For certain objects, PowerShell provides a set of formatting instructions that can affect either the table or list formats. These are usually meant to limit the display of reams of properties down to just the essential properties. However there are times when you really want to see everything. In those cases `Format-List *` will show all the properties. Note that in the case where you're trying to view a PowerShell error record, you need to use "Format-List * -Force" to truly see all the error information, for example,

```
$error[0] | Format-List * -force
```

Note that the wildcard can be used like a traditional wilcard this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_computersystem" | Format-List M*
```

Comment: I prefer `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -Property *`. It's short and sweet

Comment: @KellenStuart It is short n sweet. But it does not always list all properties. Not when I tried it.

Answer (score 50):

If you want to know what properties (and methods) there are:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_computersystem" | Get-Member
```

Comment: I am not going to mark you down because of the wording of the original question. But it is worth pointing out that Get-Member does not list the properties and their values only the property/method names and types.

Comment: This is very useful when scripting to know the type of data each field contains and to list all available field names without fetching data. Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

You can also use:

```powershell
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_computersystem" | Select *
```

This will show the same result as Format-List * used in the other answers here.

Comment: This is actually better than the method in the accepted answer, since using this method you still have rich objects, whereas using `Format-List` will destroy all of the objects down the pipeline.

Answer (score 12):

I like

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_computersystem | format-custom *
```

That seems to expand everything.

There's also a show-object command in the PowerShellCookbook module that does it in a GUI.  Jeffrey Snover, the PowerShell creator, uses it in his unplugged videos (recommended).

Although most often I use

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_computersystem | fl *
```

It avoids the .format.ps1xml file that defines a table or list view for the object type, if there are any. The format file may even define column headers that don't match any property names.

Comment: `format-custom *` seems the answer that _really_ shows everything

Answer (score 4):

The most succinct way to do this is:

```powershell
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -Property *
```

Comment: Succinct, perhaps, but incomplete.

This only lists the originally seen (5) properties vs the 83 that show up when using: Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_computersystem" | Select *

Answer (score 1):

You can list all properties of object using Four ways

**Method-1: Format-Table**

```
Get-Process | Format-Table -Property * -Wrap | Out-File abc.txt -Width 5000
OR
Get-Process | Format-Table * -Wrap | Out-File abc.txt -Width 5000
OR
Get-Process | FT * -Wrap | Out-File abc.txt -Width 5000
```

**Method-2: Format-List**

```
Get-Process | Format-List -Property *
OR
Get-Process | Format-List *
OR
Get-Process | FL *
```

**Method-3: ConvertTo-Html**

```
Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File services1.html ; invoke-item services1.html
```

**Method-4: Out-GridView**

```
Get-Process | Select * | Out-GridView
```

Comparision of results to show parameters usage:

- `Format-Table`/`Format-List` If you want to include all columns then always use `-Property *` parameter
- `Format-Table` always capture output to a file using `Out-File` because sometime not all columns are included if you show result on screen.
- `FormatTable` always specify reasonable width using `-Width` parameter otherwise column values are truncated in result.

[image]

- `Format-Table` always use -Wrap so that column with large text is not trimmed but is shown in multiple line in long column.

[image]

- `CovertTo-Html` properties with collections will only display `Type Name` of Collection insted of comma seperated values of collection items. This display is bit different from how Format-Table, Format-List & ConvertTo-Html display property with collection

[image]

Comment: using `Out-GridView` to format output of commands like `Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem` could be more user-friendly, if there was a way to transpose the table, so it lists all properties vertically instead of presenting the object as a extremely wide table