# How to tell if current node is active or passive?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a script that runs on both the active and passive nodes and I need it to figure out if it's currently on the active node or not.  I've found a little info on that with the following commands, but I want to use an if statement to filter if I'm on the active or passive node currently or not.  Does anyone have any ideas how to do that?  This is what I found so far:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_computersystem" | Format-List -Property *
```

from [properties of system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259142/how-to-see-all-properties)

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName {ClusterName}
```

from [list active node in cluster](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd67c370-8064-400a-9b10-b5d590740bc2/powershell-command-to-list-active-node-in-cluster)

I'm just not sure how to use that to see if the current node is the active one.

Comment: Active or passive nodes of what, exactly?

Comment: It's a failover cluster, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.  So it has an active node and a passive node at any given time.

Answer (score 2):

For PowerShell v3 use `Get-ClusterGroup`.  It will show what node is controlling the entire cluster, as well as, which node has control over what cluster service, disk, etc.