# GitHub Actions // PowerShell // recursive file search applying pylint

Tags: powershell, github, pylint, github-actions

I'm looking for a PowerShell version of the following Linux command for CI with GitHub actions:

```
find . -name "*.py" -not -path "./exclude_dir/*" | xargs pylint
```

here is where I'm now:

```
get-childitem -path $pwd -include *.py -recurse -name
```

at the moment I have no idea how to exclude "exclude_dir" and apply `pylint` to the selected python files.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Alexey

Comment: Bash [is available](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell) on all platforms (together with all fancy tools), you don't need to stick to PowerShell.

Comment: Since you've never accepted any answers to your questions (I haven't looked at your other ones), let me give you the standard advice in the next comment. While using Bash may be the solution you went with, future readers may still be interested in a PowerShell solution.

Answer (score 1):

While [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) does have an `-Exclude` parameter, it only operates on the *file-name* part, not on the full path.

Therefore, you must perform the exclusion filtering after the fact, using the negated form of `-like`, the [wildcard matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like)

```
pylint ((Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name -Filter *.py) -notlike 'exclude_dir/*')
```

<sup>Note the use of `-Filter` rather than `-Include`, which speeds up the operation, because filtering happens at the source rather than being applied by PowerShell after the fact.</sup>

However, given that you're seemingly only excluding a *single top-level* folder, you could try:

```
pylint (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path * -Filter *.py -Exclude exclude_dir)
```

Note that I've omitted `-Name` in this case, because it wouldn't work properly in this scenario. As a result, the matching files are implicitly passed as full paths to `pylint`.

As of PowerShell 7.0, `-Name` exhibits several problematic behaviors, which are summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60040617/45375).